# make menu ribbon slide down and up with the menu when toggled

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a hidden menu that slides down when the ribbon is clicked but the ribbon itself remains in it's position. I would like it so the ribbon slides down with the rest of the menu and likewise when closing the menu for the ribbon to slide back up.

html code

```
<div id="topbar">
    <div id="tophiddenbar" style="display: none;">
      <p>stuff goes here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu" class="ribbon">
      <p>Menu</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
#topbar {
  background: #0174C3;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  font-size: 62.5%; 
  text-align: center;
  height: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: height 0.5s linear;
  transition: height 0.5s linear;
}

#topbar.active {
    height: 250px;
}

.ribbon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #444;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

Jquery code

```
$("#menu").click(function(){
    $("#topbar").toggleClass('active');
  $("#tophiddenbar").toggle();
});
```

Codepen sample
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wZEKBz

Current default behavior when page is loaded
[image]

Current behavior when ribbon is clicked
[image]

Expected behavior when ribbon is clicked

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use another `div` with `position:relative` it will works check this answer

```
<div class="ribbon-parent">
  <div id="menu" class="ribbon">
      <p>Menu</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

```js
$("#menu").click(function(){
 $("#topbar").toggleClass('active');
  $("#tophiddenbar").toggle();
});
```

```css
#topbar {
  background: #0174C3;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  font-size: 62.5%; 
  text-align: center;
  height: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: height 0.5s linear;
  transition: height 0.5s linear;
}

#topbar.active {
 height: 250px;
}
.ribbon-parent{
  position:relative;
}
.ribbon {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;  
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #444;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
p{
font-size: 62.5%; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="topbar">
 <div id="tophiddenbar" style="display: none;">
   <p>stuff goes here</p>
 </div>  
</div>
<div class="ribbon-parent">
  <div id="menu" class="ribbon">
      <p>Menu</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

check your updated [codepen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oOPjMX)

Answer (score 1):

Gave margin-top transitions to menu as follows,

```js
$("#menu").click(function() {
    $("#topbar").toggleClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('activemenu');
    $("#tophiddenbar").toggle();
});
```

```css
#topbar {
        background: #0174C3;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 0 0 15px 0;
        font-size: 62.5%;
        text-align: center;
        height: 10px;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-transition: height 0.5s linear;
        -moz-transition: height 0.5s linear;
        transition: height 0.5s linear;
    }

    #topbar.active {
        height: 250px;
    }

    .activemenu{
        margin-top: 250px;
    }

    .ribbon {
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        left: 50%;
        width: 50px;
        height: 20px;
        background-color: #444;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-transition: margin-top 0.5s linear;
        -moz-transition: margin-top 0.5s linear;
        transition: margin-top 0.5s linear;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="topbar">
    <div id="tophiddenbar" style="display: none;">
        <p>stuff goes here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu" class="ribbon">
        <p>Menu</p>
    </div>
</div>
```